# Regex to match content between bbcode-like tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a custom implementation of bbcodes (Basically Wordpress shortcodes). For this I need to match the content that can be found between two bbcode-like tags.

For example:

```
[example]The content I want to retrieve[/example]
```

The problem is that these tags can basically be anything. It may be example this time, but it could very well be something like this:

```
[hello_world with="attribute"]And some [more-complex] content[/hello_world]
```

The only thing I need is the more complex content from the hello_world shortcode. I have found a regex that achieves this, and I modified it slightly to fit my needs:

```
(?<=\[.*\])(.*?)(?=\[.*\])
```

But when used in the following code:

```
<?php
$tag = '[test_tag with="attributes"]Content I [want] To capture[/test_tag]';

// Get the content of the shortcode.
preg_match('~(?<=\[.*\])(.*?)(?=\[.*\])~', $tag, $shortcodeContent);
var_dump($shortcodeContent);
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 10
```

Would there be an easy way to fix this error? I understand that it happens because I use a 'capture all' pattern with an unspecified length. But I'm a bit bamboozled on how I actually can fix this. (I'm not really not a regex wizard)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . For similar reasons I'd encourage you to use a BBCode parser rather than try to hack together a regex solution.

Comment: @apokryfos I wanted to learn how I could create my own implementation that basically mimics shortcodes (from Wordpress). I do appreciate you sending me the question. It was an interesting read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstand your question**, then you can do this way to capture the internal text content using this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2Dlnxj/2).

```
<?php

$re = '/(?<=\])(.*?)(?=\[\/)/m';
$str = '[test_tag with="attributes"]Content I [want] To capture[/test_tag]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
echo $matches[0][0];
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/qgcNg

Comment: How did you omit the error with a lookbehind? I'm quite interested in how I can omit this in the possible future.

Comment: @GuylianWasHier Have a look on my demo regex here: https://regex101.com/r/2Dlnxj/2

Comment: @GuylianWasHier glad it helps you somehow :) happy coding!

Comment: There is no reason for the `m` pattern modifier on this pattern because there are no anchors (e.g. `^` or `$`).  Perhaps you mean to write the `s` pattern modifier that will allow dots to match newlines as well.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes agreed with you sir

Comment: I will leave this simple edit to you.  However, I have larger concerns -- this answer in no way tries to identify bbcode tags... it is just looking for square braces.  Looks very unreliable to me.